# How to get small images from big Bufferedimage really fast

Tags: java, performance, image, bufferedimage, clip

I had a BufferedImage an image of size (100mb) pixels  6720x9239 and needed many small images with pixels 60x60

firstly i used this code i found on the net

```
 BufferedImage bi= ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    ......
//in paint()
Image b=createImage(new FilteredImageSource(bi.getSource(),
        new CropImageFilter(x, y , 60, 60)));
```

needed to wait around 1 to 5 secs for each small image very slow because i my app needed like 50 images which would mean ppl would have to w8 from 50 to 5*50 sec for panel to reload, so i chan that to

```
BufferedImage bi= ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    ......
//in paint()
BufferedImage a = imageMap.getSubimage(x, y , 60, 60);
            Image b = createImage(a.getSource());
```

feel really happy now had to let the world know this

Comment: Well the reason for that is quite obvious. The second image shares the data with the original while the first doesn't. So the two aren't equivalent and it depends on WHAT you want to do with it (in your case the 2nd is obviously the better choice not just for performance reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god you solved my problem which had stumped me for like 5 days. I had just finished typing out the question and was about to submit it. APPARENTLY (now that I know using Images works) when you use a bufferedImage in g2d.drawImage(Image, at, this) the drawing is MUCH slower than if you use an Image. Something like 50x slower. By converting the BufferedImages to Images (I didn't know you could do that, less that would solve the problem) like this:
Inside the loadBullets function:

```
        BufferedImage a;
    Image b;
 a = spriteSheetPositive.getSubimage(
                //going to use the same image 252 times until I get the motherload of data string converted to the format:
                //sprites[shotId]=spriteSheetPositive.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
                520, //x  520,1,536,16 (small lime star) id=100
                1, //y
                16, //width
                15 //height
                );
        b= createImage(a.getSource());
        sprites[shotID]=b;
```

I can now use images from a spritesheet as projectile sprites with as many as 1,000 on screen at time with no lag! Hooray!

### My original question:

This is code within the paint function:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Projectiles.size(); i++) {


        Shot02 m = (Shot02) Projectiles.get(i);
        //m.getImage();
      //  g2d.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getIntX(), m.getIntY(), this);


        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        // 4. translate it to the center of the component
        at.translate(m.getDrawX(), m.getDrawY());
        // 3. do the actual rotation

        at.rotate(m.getAngle()); //rotation is Clockwise
        g2d.drawImage(m.getImage(), at, this);


    }
```

I am working on a platformer perspective shooting game. I switched from using a simple imageicon image to a bufferedImage created as a subImage from a sprite sheet. However, as a result of that the program lags with as little as 20 projectiles on screen, whereas previously I could have up to around 1000.

```
private void loadBullets() {//is done only once, when the window starts
    // Get Image
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("AbsoluteWin\\CustomShotsPositive.png"));
    Image image = icon.getImage();

    // Create empty BufferedImage, sized to Image
    BufferedImage spriteSheetPositive =
            new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(null),
            image.getHeight(null),
            Transparency.BITMASK);


    // Draw Image into BufferedImage
    Graphics g = spriteSheetPositive.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    int shotID = 1;
    System.out.println(shotID);

    while (shotID <= length) {//fills the array with the bullets from the sprite sheet spriteSheetPositive
        sprites[shotID] = spriteSheetPositive.getSubimage(
                //going to use the same image 252 times until I get the coordinates for all the other sub-images
                //sprites[shotId]=spriteSheetPositive.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
                520, //x  520,1,536,16 (small lime star) id=100
                1, //y
                16, //width
                15 //height
                );

        shotID += 1;

    }
    System.out.println(shotID);
}
```

Shot02 Class:

```
        ImageIcon ii =
            new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("missile.png"));
    image = ii.getImage();

   //image=Destination.sprites[100];//is the source
```

This is the code in the Shot02 Class that controls the what image the bullets use. Again, if I uncomment the second option and use the BufferedImages, the program slows down like crazy.