# Assign part of BufferedImage to another BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, clip

I am doing one application in Java and I want to do this:
I have a `BufferedImage` with a large image loaded and I want to assign a part of it to another `BufferedImage`.

Let's say

```
BufferedImage2 = BufferedImage1.GetWindow(From x1 y1  to x2 y2);
```

`BufferedImage2` will be just a small part of the greater `BufferedImage1`.

Comment: What is BufferedImage? What does GetWindow() return?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317732/how-to-get-small-images-from-big-bufferedimage-really-fast

Comment: The method you are looking for, is `BufferedImage.getSubimage()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133993/what-exactly-does-getsubimage-of-bufferedimage-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`BufferedImage.getSubimage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
int width = x2 - x1;
int height = y2 - y1;
BufferedImage bufferedImage2 = bufferedImage1.getSubimage(x1, y1, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance drawing in the image buffer:

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = img2.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(bufferedImage1, x, y, width, height, null);
g.dispose();
```

There are several `drawImage` methods, see the javadoc. You probably want this [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).